# Error on Tridion Core Service while executing "client.Save" or "client.Update" method

Tags: core-service, sites-9

We are using Tridion Sites 9.0 and while executing `client.Save()/client.Update()` method we are getting an error -
`Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.11.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

We have installed the specific/recent version of `HtmlAgilityPack` dependency from NuGet. But still we are getting same error.

Is there any dependency with `Core Service Assembly` with `HtmlAgilityPack?`

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Does this error originate from the server or the client?

Comment: Hello @Quirijn This error is originated in client..